# Merge statement array as source table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, merge, oracle10g

Is it possible to use array as source for merge statement

E.g. I have the below merge statement and when I compile, I am getting error.
How can I use merge with array as source table?

```
PLS-00436: implementation restriction: cannot reference fields of BULK In-BIND 
table of records
```

Procedure code

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (varray IN my_array)
     AS
     BEGIN
          FORALL i IN varray.first..varray.last
          MERGE INTO tab t
          USING dual
          ON ( t.proj_id = varray(i).proj_id)
          WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE  set
          proj_title = varray (i).proj_title
                      WHERE   proj_id = varray (i).proj_id
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            insert (proj_id,proj_title)
            values (varray (i).proj_id,varray (i).proj_title);
         values (varray (i).proj_id,varray (i).proj_title);
```

Comment: Check this article for workarounds: [PLS-00436 in 10g - Workaround](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=410)

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej Thanks a ton, this really helped. So it is a limitation in 10g right?

Comment: Yes, in 11g you can access individual fields of records in `FORALL` statement, unlike in 10g where you get the error that you have linked to your question.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej If you post as an answer I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a restriction in Oracle 10g - you can't access individual fields of records in `FORALL` statement. You could do it if you were using Oracle 11g.

There are workarounds, however, and I recommend the following article that proposes a few of them: [PLS-00436 in 10g - Workaround](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=410).

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are referring to the same collection in your `SET` clause and `WHERE` clause. See [Oracle Documentation for Forall statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/forall_statement.htm), go to the Restrictions section, second bullet point.

I would suggest you rename your `varray` collection as something different, as it is a keyword. I would also suggest you separate this collection into multiple scalar collections (varrays or nested tables having only one column) for each column and then use these collections in your forall statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the source dataset in the `MERGE` clause by selecting it from `DUAL`:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create table projects (
  2     proj_id integer not null primary key,
  3     proj_title varchar2(20)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into projects (proj_id, proj_title) values (1, 'Project One');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into projects (proj_id, proj_title) values (2, 'Project Two');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select *
  2    from projects;

   PROJ_ID PROJ_TITLE
---------- --------------------
         1 Project One
         2 Project Two

2 rows selected.

SQL> declare
  2     type varray_t is varray(2) of projects%rowtype;
  3     arr varray_t;
  4  begin
  5     with test_data as (select 2 as proj_id, 'New Project Two' as proj_title from dual
  6                        union all select 3 as proj_id, 'New Project Three' as proj_title from dual)
  7     select proj_id, proj_title
  8       bulk collect into arr
  9       from test_data;
 10
 11     forall i in arr.first .. arr.last
 12        merge into projects
 13        using (select arr(i).proj_id as proj_id,
 14                      arr(i).proj_title as proj_title
 15                 from dual) mrg
 16           on (projects.proj_id = mrg.proj_id)
 17         when matched then update set projects.proj_title = mrg.proj_title
 18         when not matched then insert (proj_id, proj_title) values (mrg.proj_id, mrg.proj_title);
 19
 20     dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount || ' rows merged');
 21
 22     commit;
 23  end;
 24  /
2 rows merged

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select *
  2    from projects;

   PROJ_ID PROJ_TITLE
---------- --------------------
         1 Project One
         2 New Project Two
         3 New Project Three

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Would you happen to know if using this DUAL workaround ends up serializing, or if the merge happens in one shot? In other words, does the FORALL with USING ... FROM DUAL first create a view with all records from the associative array, and then perform the merge from this view? Or does it perform one merge for each record in the associative array?